# How this primitive binding works in laravel, please give example

Tags: laravel

```
$this->app->when('App\Http\Controllers\UserController')
      ->needs('$variableName')
      ->give($value);
```

How to use above binding in controller?

thanks @apokryfos for explain.

At controller side:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function __construct($variableName)
   { 
      //here we get the $value
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't use above binding in controller. The above binding is used when the controller is being constructed. It will pass `$value` as the value for `$variableName` assuming the controller constructor requires a variable called `$variableName` to be passed.

Comment: Thank you, can you put an example  of controller with contructor.. I am still confused!

Comment: You mean like `class UserController extends Controller { public function __construct($variableName) { /* ... */ } }` ?